# Macbook Pro 2015 Crashes when plugging and/or unplugging HDMI

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi

It's a brand new 2015 and I move from office to classroom all the time, plugging and unplugging HDMI. Fairly often the machine either goes black or literally hard crashes with the multi-lingual crash message.

Is this a known issue? Is there a different/better way to deal with changing from one HDMI to another one?

Comment: Do you use the original, white Apple HDMI adapter or a Third-Party adapter?

Comment: You mean the cable? The projector in the classroom uses an unknown cable, and the one in my office is a non-apple cable. Could it be the actual cable?